# Why can this recurrence relation be rewritten like this?

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations

I have the recurrence relation: $a(n)= a(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor)+a(\lceil n/2 \rceil)+3n+1$ with $a_1 =3$. This can be solved to have the explicit formula: $\frac{3\cdot log_2(n)\cdot n+4\cdot log_2(2)\cdot n - log_2(2)}{log_2(2)}$. I was just "playing around" with this recurrence relation in maple and found this to be its explicit formula. I then wondered for quite some time about *how* or *why* this was its explicit formula. So can anyone show me the steps to get to that result?

Comment: I don't think the formula is correct. $a(2)=13$ while the formula gives $10$.

Comment: Well spotted.. Should be fixed now :)

Comment: You have repeated $a(n/2)$ twice. Is that correct? Why not expressing it as $2a(n/2)+3n+1$?

Comment: Also, can I assume that you mean something like $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ instead of $n/2$?  The recurrence as written doesn't allow us to compute $a_3$.

Comment: @Slade Yes, indeed. I just could not figure out how to write ceilings and floors :) The one occurrence of a(n/2) would be a ceiling, the other a floor.

Comment: I've updated the post with ceilings and floors.  Could you please update any other details that are missing?

Comment: Thanks. No other details are missing :-)

Answer (score 2):

Let $n=2^m$, then $a(2^m)= a(2^{m-1})+a(2^{m-1})+3·2^m+1$

Define $b(m)=a(2^m)$, so we have $b(m)=2b(m-1)+3·2^m+1$

This is an inhomogeneous linear recurrence law. This kind of sequences have as explicit formula the sum of a general solution for the homogeneous law and a particular solution for the inhomogeneous one.

Let's try $b(m)=Ar^m$, for some $A$ and $r$, for the homogeneous:

$Ar^m=2Ar^{m-1}$ only possible if $r=2$

For the inhomogeneous, let's try $b(m)=Dm2^m+E$. Substituting in the recurrence relation we get $D=3$ and $E=-1$. So,

$b(m)=A2^m+3m2^m-1$

Now, with the condition $b(0)=3$ (because $a(2^0)=3$), we can find $A$: $3=A-1$ or $A=4$

$b(m)=4·2^m+3m2^m-1$

$a(n)=b(\log_2n)=4n+3n\log_2n-1$

as expected.

Comment: Thanks! However, I think I need some clarification: So you are rewriting the original inhomogeneous linear relation as a homogenous linear relation? Why is $Ar^m =2Ar^{m-1}$ only possible if r=2? What law are you talking about?

Comment: As the relation is linear, the sum of two solutions is too a solution. I solve first $b(m)=2b(m-1)$ Call the solution $b_0$. Call the particular solution $b_1$. $b=b_0+b_1$ is solution too: $b_0(m)+b_1(m)=2b_0(m-1)+2b_1(m-1)+3·2^m+1$ but we can cancel the terms for $b_0$ and the remaining is the equation for $b_1$

Comment: I use "recurrence law" as synonym of "recurrence relation". In $Ar^m =2Ar^{m-1}$ simplify as much as you can and, what do you get?

Comment: I know it has been some time, but I am just starting to get it now. So you split the recurrence relation into two parts: one for the homogenous part and one for the inhomogeneous, right?  Secondly, how did you come up with the idea to replace n with $2^m$? Finally, when you were solving the inhomogeneous part, why did you use $Dm2^m+E$ and not just $D2^m+E$ since in the recurrence relation $3$ is only multiplied by $2^m$ and not $m$? Oh and why is the last part linear? If you are kind enou to answer, please update the answer rather than some very complex comments :-)

Comment: I know it is a lot, but it would me so much! You seem to be a smart guy so I better try to extract some elaboration :-)

Comment: Linear recurrence relations are exponential general terms, the base of which are found making the substitution I did. If you have an explicit term in the recurrence relation, the usual procedure is to try with a term of the same form. In this case is a good try to use a polynomial multiplying the exponential (plus a constant for the constant in the recurrence relation)  It can or cannot work! but in this case it did.

Comment: You didn't ask me about the reason to choose the variable change in the first step. It's too a try, an "educated guess" suggested by the properties of the exponentials (they transform products into sums) and the solution you gave, full of logarithms!